# No signal to Monitor after uninstalling graphics drivers

Tags: drivers, display, graphics-card, dvi, vga

I have a pair of ATI 5770's in crossfire and today I decided to do a clean install of my graphics drivers. So, my plan was to:

- Uninstall drivers
- Boot into safe mode and run driver sweeper
- Boot back into Windows to reinstall drivers

I didn't even get to stage 2. After uninstalling the drivers I don't seem to be able to get a signal to my monitor no matter how hard I try. The attempts I've made to solve the problem are:

- Tried both DVI and both VGA slots since there are 2 GPU's
- Resetting the BIOS by removing the CMOS battery for a few minutes

No luck. To clarify, I don't even get a signal to the monitor at any point; not even during the POST process. It does POST just fine, though.

Comment: Have you tried with just one of the cards?

Comment: Some system boards won't initialize the display on the topmost card for some reason, and killing the drivers would reset that.  You /should/ be getting display on whichever screen you normally have POST on.  You should try unplugging all but one display and trying each port individually; ONE of them should have a display.  Barring that, remove all but one of the cards.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting any signal to your monitor even at the initial stages of boot or at the BIOS screen, you might have a hardware issue.

At any stage, have you opened up your case (to vacuum the dust, to read the model number from the cards, etc.)? Do we have the full picture or have you actually done anything beyond what you described above?

If you've touched any hardware, I would try trying the video cards one by one, trying your RAMs one by one (you might have fried them with static electricity from your fingers etc.), press down on cards, cables to make sure they're securely attached, etc.